# How to serialize deserialize mongodate in php

Tags: php, json, mongodb, serialization

I currently have many remote sites running instances of software and storing data in MongoDB. This works fine.

I'm working on a PHP API that can be used to securely provide the endpoint / remote site data. To a central system or to other specific users. The API provides the data back as JSON.

My issue is that when the central system queries the API, it gets the data back, inserts the data into the database, and it works fine, except for MongoDate objects. If I specifically pull that data out, use the objects sec and usec fields, then overwrite the value, it does store the ISODate in Mongo correctly.

The problem with that is that the system utilizes the dynamic nature of Mongo and the exact keys for the Mongo ISODate fields may not be known by the central service.

If I directly query the central Mongo, the value for the incorrectly serialized/deserialized ISODates is:

```
    "myTime" : {
        "sec" : NumberLong(1425486541),
        "usec" : NumberLong(105000)
    },
```

These values are not able to be queried using normal Mongo time queries.

If I "manually" edit and reassign value to the variable in the central PHP script by creating a new MongoDate object from the sec and usec values, it looks like:

```
"myTime" : ISODate("2015-04-16T19:46:46.082Z"),
```

Is there a known, proper way of using PHP to Serialize and Deserialize the MongoDate objects in JSON?

I am tempted to try using the standard PHP object serialization/deserialization, but then only other PHP clients can consume the data. It would be much more preferable to use JSON as it is a much more standard structure.

--

I just found this open issue discussing the issue:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-203

MongoDB Extended JSON also has support for this data type: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/

It looks like the issue is that PHP doesn't implement the extended json format for json_encode and json_decode.

Answer (score -1):

Convert JSON string to PHP array:

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
$arr = json_decode($json, true)
var_dump($arr);
```

After this, you can use smt like that: (only example)

```
date('d.m.y H:i:s',$arr['myTime']['sec'])
```

Comment: This won't work as the data structures are dynamic and the end user may or may not have the latest application layer translations to unmap the document. A standard JSON serializable and deserializable solution is needed.